# How to control static dependencies of objects across translation units?

Tags: c++

In C++, if static objects that have dependencies between them are defined in *different* translation units, the language itself provides no guarantee on the order of initialization.

Bruce Eckel gives an example ("Thinking in C++"):

The first file defines an `ofstream` object named `out`:

```
//: C10:Out.cpp {O}
// (c) Bruce Eckel 2000
// First file

#include <fstream>

std::ofstream out("out.txt"); ///:~
```

The second file has a dependency on the `ofstream` object out:

```
//: C10:Oof.cpp
// (c) Bruce Eckel 2000
// Second file

#include <fstream>

extern std::ofstream out;


class Oof
{
public:
   Oof()
   {
      out << "ouch"; 
   }
} oof;


int main()
{
} ///:~
```

When these 2 files are built and linked to create an executable, the exe will work only if the first file is initialized before the second file; else the program will crash.

Eckel provides two solutions.

The first solution involves a technique (pioneered by Jerry Schwarz) and uses an Initializer class in the library header file. The Initializer class is responsible for the dynamic initialization of the library’s static objects.

Eckel provides an example that dynamically initializes 2 static global variables of built-in types.

The basic technique is quite clear to me.

He then goes on state:

> This example used built-in types as the global static objects. The technique also works with classes, but those objects must then be dynamically initialized by the Initializer class. One way to do this is to create the classes without constructors and destructors, but instead with initialization and cleanup member functions using different names. A more common approach, however, is to have pointers to objects and to create them using new inside Initializer( ).

I have the following queries about Eckel's statement:

1) Why is it necessary to create the classes without constructors and destructors, but instead with initialization and cleanup member functions using different names?
2) How can the approach that uses pointers to objects be used?
3) Examples would be of great help.

Comment: Example might be https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Nifty_Counter.
they use placement new instead of `Init` function

Comment: Why don't you try *not* having global static objects in the first place? Then all your problems go away.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, an avoidance strategy is the _best_ approach. However, Schwarz's technique is for when such a strategy isn't possible.